# Differentiation of $e^y$

Tags: derivatives

$$e^{x^2-2x-1.5}$$

How can you differentiate the above expression?

I know the derivative of $e^x$ is itself, but do not know I could use that to solve this problem. I would like to solve this problem without using the chain rule, product rule, and quotient rule...Is it possible?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule

Comment: well, in your game, which operation do you allow, then ? At least, do you allow computing $ lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ ?

Comment: I guess you could do without the chain rule by _proving_ what amounts to the chain rule in one specific case, but what would be the point?

Comment: I've learnt the first principles, and the derivatives of a few common functions (like the trig and log functions) so far, and wanted to see if this could be done with my knowledge right now.

Comment: What would be the reason for NOT using the chain rule?  It is quick and pretty painless....

Comment: Well, [e^(x^2 + 2xh + h^2 -2x -2h -1.5) - e^(x^2x^2  -2x-1.5)]/h =e^(x^2 - 2x -1.5)[1 - etc. ... but why....

Answer (score 2):

For sure, the chain rule applies.  $$y=e^{f(x)}\implies y'=f'(x)\,e^{f(x)}$$ But, if this looks simpler to you, you can use logarithmic differentiation  $$y=e^{f(x)}\implies\log(y)=f(x)\implies\frac {y'}y=f'(x)\implies y'=f'(x) y=f'(x)\,e^{f(x)}$$